# how to import node npm module in angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, import, angular6

I have installed the package

```
npm install local-devices
```

and imported it in `angular.json` as

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/local-devices/index.js"
]
```

and declared as `global variable` in `src/typings.d.ts`

```
declare let findLocalDevices: any
```

Below, `package` files structure and `index.js` of `local-devices` package

[image][image]

then tried to use it in a component as

```
console.log(findLocalDevices())
```

but got error

> findLocalDevices is not defined

How to import it, please guide!!!

Answer (score 9):

```
import * as findLocalDevices from 'local-devices'
```

and inside any method use it as

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(findLocalDevices());
}
```

you may require to install other packages also os child_process / mz

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '\node_modules\mz'. How to resolve this?